# use variable in range statement

Tags: excel, vba

My code is designed to find the first empty cell in column a, set a variable to it, and then using that variable find the cell 3 columns over in the same row.

```
 'Find Last empty cell in first column
Dim rngSelect As Range
Dim rngFstAcCell As Range
Dim rngLstAcCell As Range

Set rngSelect = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
MsgBox rngSelect.Address    'just to check
rngFstAcCell = Range(rngSelect.Address).Offset(0, 3)
```

Object variable or with block variable not set on the last statement is what I am getting. 
What am I doing wrong with that line.
What I am trying to do is re-use the variable rngSelect...as a learning exercise.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `Set`.  Also you already have a Range object in `rngSelect`, so you don't need to use `Address` and `Range` like that.

```
Set rngFstAcCell = rngSelect.Offset(0, 3)
```

Comment: worked perfectly - why didn't i think of that.  thanks